# WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR when invoking a web service Java - SOAP/CXF

Tags: java, spring, soap, cxf

I am migrating an app running with java 1.7 and jboss-eap-6.1 to java 1.8 and wildfly-18.0.0.Final.

Everything is working pretty well, but i'm facing a problem when calling a particular external web service using SOAP.

I have this error when I call the service:

```
Caused by: org.w3c.dom.DOMException: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than 
the one that created it.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.internalInsertBefore(ParentNode.java:357)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.insertBefore(ParentNode.java:288)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NodeImpl.appendChild(NodeImpl.java:237)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.util.WSSecurityUtil.prependChildElement(WSSecurityUtil.java:375)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.util.WSSecurityUtil.findWsseSecurityHeaderBlock(WSSecurityUtil.java:497)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.message.WSSecHeader.insertSecurityHeader(WSSecHeader.java:167)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.handler.WSHandler.doSenderAction(WSHandler.java:117)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor.access$100(WSS4JOutInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor$WSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessageInternal(WSS4JOutInterceptor.java:275)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor$WSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(WSS4JOutInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor$WSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(WSS4JOutInterceptor.java:132)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:530)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:441)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:356)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:314)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:140)
    ... 112 more
```

All the other services are working, except this one.
When I look at the spring context xml file, I see that this service has an extra configuration which is a **WSS4JOutInterceptor** bean.

```
<bean id="outInterceptorWSS" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor">
    <property name="properties">
        <map>
            <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken"/>
            <entry key="mustUnderstand" value="false"/>
            <entry key="user" value="username here"/>
            <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordNone"/>
            <entry key="passwordCallbackClass"
                   value="PasswordHandler package here"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myServiceFactory" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="serviceClass"
                  value="service package here"/>
        <property name="address"
                  value="endpointUrl here"/>
        <property name="username"
                  value="username here"/>
        <property name="password"
                  value="password here"/>
        <property name="outInterceptors" ref="outInterceptorWSS"/>
        <property name="bus" ref="cxf"/>
    </bean>
```

The **outInterceptorWSS** bean is use to add security header in the soap message before the call to the external web service.
The service works well before the migration (java 1.7 and jboss-eap-6-1), but doesn't work after the migration (java 1.8 and wildfly-18.0.0.Final).

I am not 100% sure, but my understanding of this problem is that wildfly creates the soap message, and the **outInterceptorWS** bean defined in the spring context xml file tries to modify it, thus the message : *A node is used in a different document than the one that created it*

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm facing the same problem right now and am not having much luck.

Comment: Hi @dracuella
It was a problem of version of the library in our wildfly. We had to add manually the good version of  the jar in our wildfly modules folder. 
It's saturday and i don't have access to our code from home. Monday i'll check our code and give you more details if any.

Comment: did you find any details on which jars you had to add? If you upgraded or downgraded?

Comment: hello @dracuella. Sorry for my late response. You can see my answer below for the details. Hope it helps. Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

add new version of saaj-impl to your project.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
            <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

We finally found a solution for this problem.
We had to add the saaj jar manually in our wildfly modules directory. To do that, we create a folder in this directory: **${YOUR_WILDFLY_HOME}/modules/system/layers/base/com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/main**.

In this folder we had 2 files: the **saaj-impl-1.3.16-jbossorg-1.jar** (downloaded from Maven) and a **module.xml** file for the saaj jar.
This is the content of the module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
~ JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source.
~ Copyright 2011, Red Hat, Inc., and individual contributors
~ as indicated by the @author tags. See the copyright.txt file in the
~ distribution for a full listing of individual contributors.
~
~ This is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
~ under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as
~ published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of
~ the License, or (at your option) any later version.
~
~ This software is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
~ but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
~ MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
~ Lesser General Public License for more details.
~
~ You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
~ License along with this software; if not, write to the Free
~ Software Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA
~ 02110-1301 USA, or see the FSF site: http://www.fsf.org.
-->
<module name="com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.5">
<properties>
    <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
</properties>
<resources>
    <resource-root path="saaj-impl-1.3.16-jbossorg-1.jar"/>
</resources>

<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.xml.soap.api"/>
    <module name="javax.xml.stream.api"/>
    <module name="javax.activation.api"/>
    <module name="org.apache.xerces" services="import"/>
</dependencies>

</module>
```

Comment: Thank you. We already had the mentioned jar in JBoss (EAP 7.3.1) but you sent us in the right direction. It was indeed a saaj problem, we just fixed it in the application rather than directly in JBoss.